# merge excel data to rename filenames in R

Tags: r, merge, rename

I believe R would allow me to do what I want to do with minimal code, but I am a beginner and struggling.

I have many csv files. I already name them as "city_school_class"

[image]

Now I have the other excel file "classinfo", looks like

[image]

How to merge "id" from classinfo to rename the files for loop in R as

[image]

here is how I name my files (I got them with many irregular name)

```
for (file_original in dir("original", full.names = TRUE)) {
df <- read.csv(file_original)
filename <- paste(df[1,"city"], df[1,"school"], df[1,"class"], sep = "_")
file_rename <- paste0("rename/", filename, ".csv")
print(file_rename)
write.csv(df, file_rename)
}
```

greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you reading in the csv-files with `read_xlsx`?

Comment: Are you looking for `do.call(paste, c(classinfo, sep = '_'))`?

Comment: @Wimpel  my bad. it should be `read.csv`

Comment: @Sotos  it looks like what I need. Unfortunately I still can't use it to merge id of schoolinfo into my filename